# Baseclass function not working on my subclass - php

Tags: php, inheritance

I have a base class

```
class View {
private $inner;

public function setInner($inner) {
    $this->inner = $inner;
}

public function template($inner) {
    $this->setInner($inner);

    echo <<<HTML
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
          WebCrawler
        </title>
        <meta name="description" content="The URL Link Finder">
        <meta name="author" content="JohnW">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
      </head>
      <body>
            <!--Inner html-->
            {$this->inner}
            <!-- Inner html-->.....
```

I have a subclass which extends that class

```
class NewUserView extends View {

private $inner = 'Please enter your details here';

//for new users to sign up
public function show() {
    $this->body = <<<HTML
    <body>
        <!--Inner html-->
        {$this->inner}
        <!-- Inner html-->
        <br/>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            Name: <input t....
```

Therefore when I create an instance of NewUserView I expected to be able to change the $inner string via the following commands.

```
        $view = new NewUserView;
    $view->setInner($this->sessionSignUp($value));
    $view->show();
```

However the original $inner, 'please set your details' is still shown on my view, when it should be the string passed in from the sessionSignUp function. Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Make `$inner` protected instead of private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer telling you to make $inner protected instead of private was correct.

To elaborate:
Private properties/member variables are only accessible to the class they belong to.
Protected properties are accessible to the owning class and any of its descendants.